# What does optimizer do in Apache Pig architecture?

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I am new to Apache Pig and trying to understand its architecture.

Link referred - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_architecture.htm

Can anyone explain what is the role of Optimizer in Apache Pig architecture?

It says:

> The Directed Acyclic Graph generated by the Parser is passed to the logical optimizer, which carries out the logical optimizations such as projection and pushdown.

I am unclear what does `projection` and `pushdown` mean.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous optimizations done by Pig and you can read more about them here: https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/perf.html#optimization-rules. Let's look at the optimizations you mentioned in slightly more depth:

#### Pushdown Optimzation

`Pushdown` or `predicate-pushdown` is a common optimization in many languages like Pig, Hive, Spark, SQL etc. A gist of the `predicate-pushdown` concept (source: http://www.dbms2.com/2014/07/15/the-point-of-predicate-pushdown/):

- If you issue a query in one place to run against a lot of data that’s in another place, you could spawn a lot of network traffic, which could be slow and costly.
- However …
  … if you can “push down” parts of the query to where the data is stored, and thus filter out most of the data, then you can greatly reduce network traffic.

In the scope of Pig, the `PredicatePushdownOptimizer`, the optimizer pushes relevant filter condition(s) to the loader as a hint to possibly filter out data as early as possible in the data ETL pipeline. (Reference: https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/perf.html#optimization-rules#PredicatePushdownOptimizer)

#### Projection Optimization

`Projection` or `ColumnMapKeyPrune` is an optimization done by Pig to prune the loader to only load necessary columns. The corresponding loader must of course support column pruning. This optimization also has the same idea in mind as the `pushdown` optimization by limiting the data at the earliest possible step in the data ETL pipeline. (Reference: https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/perf.html#optimization-rules#ColumnMapKeyPrune)